# Special Character on Includes

Tags: php, utf-8

Whenever i use include() to load a php file, the £ (pound signs) are converted to the diamond question mark (what's the name for this btw?).
The head has UTF-8 specified, and on the main pages everything works, but only on the includes is this happening.
A simple fix for me would be to use the HTML codes to load these characters, but i'm more interested in WHY this is happening than trying to find a workaround.

Thanks.

Comment: My bet is your file itself is not UTF-8

Comment: @Machavity will check that out now, thank you.
Will return here with the solution for others if needed.

Comment: So from what i understand, i need to call mysql_set_charset($link, 'utf8mb4'); ??

The majority of the SQL tables are in latin1_swedish_ci and the rest utf-8.

Comment: You might be able to get with something a bit lighter, like `utf8_general` or `utf8_unicode`, but `utf8mb4` is the only true UTF8 collation. `latin1_swedish_ci` is not really suitable for web development anymore

Comment: Check out Google. Lots of tutorials there